# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when i am trying to get html from json

Tags: javascript

i am learning json how to use in front-end and everything was going good but now i am getting one error.

where is the token i am really not understand this error

```
var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");

var btn =  document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://webwizardservices.com/first-1.json');
ourRequest.onload = function(){
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    renderHTML(ourData);
};

ourRequest.send();   
});

function renderHTML (data){
var passhtml ="";

for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){

    passhtml+= "<p>" + data[i].names + "is a " + data[i].scpcies + ".</p>";

}   

    animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','passhtml',);
}
```

Comment: That's a String not an Element. Why not use something like `animalContainer.innerHTML += passhtml;`, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma (`,`) here:

```
animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','passhtml',);
```

*Unexpected token* usually is a syntax/parsing error.

I suggest using a linter like [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) (there are others) with your editor. It checks syntax (and other rules) while you're editing your file and helps finding errors like this and keep standards (indentation, semicolons or not, single/double quotes...).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion this is working for me 

animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',passhtml);